# nuxt middleware not getting updated store value

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

i am calling the middleware in this way inside the page.

```
export default {
layout:'dashboard',
components: {},
 name: "my-component",
 middleware: 'authenticate',
```

and in my middleware

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
// If the user is not authenticated

if (!store.state.myaccount.auth.isAuthenticated) {
  redirect('/login')
}
```

}

when i alert the store value in my page in mounted the updated value "true" appears but it cant catch the change in middleware.it always shows "false"
how can i get rid of this problem.?

Comment: do you rerun `npm run dev` after creating the middleware?

Comment: i did..but that didnt solve my problem

Comment: try `console.log(store.state.myaccount.auth.isAuthenticated)` in your middleware, what will be printed?

Comment: i've tried this basic things..it shows false.

Comment: maybe a smallest reproduction on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) may help. you provided too little info

Comment: Or codesandbox. Would be better.